# How to find the JS function being called from Chrome Dev Tools in Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on trying to find a defect in an angular application in the javascript being used to scroll a page. Person clicks link, page scrolls. Simple.

Alas, I have no idea what functions are actually being called when a user clicks the link and given this app consists of dozens and dozens (and dozens) of separate files, I'm having trouble finding what's going on.

I've read about using breakpoints and setting them up via the SOURCES tab in devtools. However, regardless of which of the many JS files I open in there, I never get any breakpoint options to check.

Is there a way to see what JS is getting fired with a particular event on the page within Chrome's Devtools?

Comment: You can set a breakpoint by clicking the line number to the left of the line you want to pause before.  It will make a little blue arrow.

Comment: @shiftweave I have no idea what function I'm looking for, let alone which JS file it's in or what line number it's at. None of this is my code.

Comment: There is an Event Listeners tab in Chrome Dev Tools that lists all the event listeners attached to the various elements. Note though some might link to a library that set the listener (ie if using jQuery will link to the jQuery subsystem)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `Sources` tab.
2. Unfold `Event Listener Breakpoints`
3. Unfold `Control`, check `scroll` checkbox.
4. Scroll the page.

Javascript runtime will stop on event listener bound to page scroll and place will be showed in main window under `Sources` tab. If it's library file (in You case Angular files), right click on the file and `Blackbox script`. Scroll page again ;)